# How to build a new tuple in Haskell by adding a element to a given tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples, operators, addition

How can I add an element to a tuple?

Say, I have a tuple:

```
info = (13, "Arrabella")
```

Now I want to create a new tuple conatining the given tuple plus a new element `3.17`, so when starting with `a` the resulting tuple should be like following:

```
(13, "Arrabella", 3.17)
```

Any idea how to do this? The `++` operator I'd use to do this with a `List` doesn't seem to be implemented for tuples...

Comment: Most of the desire to do something like this goes away if you use domain-specific product types (e.g. `data Student = Student { age: int, name: string }`) instead of tuples. (Nobody would ask how to add a GPA to a `Student`; they'd ask how to do something like define a function that takes a `Student` and a GPA and returns a `GradedStudent` value.)

Answer (score 2):

You can map the existing values to a new 3-tuple, so:

```
info2 = (i1, i2, 3.17) where (i1, i2) = info
```

> The `++` operator I'd use to do this with a List doesn't seem to be implemented for tuples...

Indeed, [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) takes two lists and returns a list that is the concatenation of the two given lists. This also means that the items in the list all have the same type, and that the items in the two lists have the same type.

One could make a typeclass to concatenate tuples with an arbitrary length, for example with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class TupleAppend a b c | a b -> c where
    (+++) :: a -> b -> c

instance TupleAppend (a, b) (c, d) (a, b, c, d) where
    (a, b) +++ (c, d) = (a, b, c, d)

instance TupleAppend (a, b) (c, d, e) (a, b, c, d, e) where
    (a, b) +++ (c, d, e) = (a, b, c, d, e)

-- …


instance TupleAppend (a, b, c) (d, e) (a, b, c, d, e) where
    (a, b, c) +++ (d, e) = (a, b, c, d, e)

instance TupleAppend (a, b, c) (d, e, f) (a, b, c, d, e, f) where
    (a, b, c) +++ (d, e, f) = (a, b, c, d, e, f)

-- …
```

But this will not help here either since you here add one element to the tuple, not concatenate two tuples. You can create an extra typeclass to append a single item:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class TupleAddL a b c | a b -> c where
    (<++) :: a -> b -> c

class TupleAddR a b c | a b -> c where
    (++>) :: a -> b -> c

instance TupleAddL a (b, c) (a, b, c) where
    a <++ (b, c) = (a, b, c)

instance TupleAddR (a, b) c (a, b, c) where
    (a, b) ++> c = (a, b, c)

instance TupleAddL a (b, c, d) (a, b, c, d) where
    a <++ (b, c, d) = (a, b, c, d)

instance TupleAddR (a, b, c) d (a, b, c, d) where
    (a, b, c) ++> d = (a, b, c, d)

-- …
```

Then you thus can use `(13, "Arrabella") ++> 3.17` to create a 3-tuple.

Comment: Cool. The "unpacking" solution `info2 = (i1, i2, 3.17) where (i1, i2) = info` is a great way to look at the problem and it works. However you need to know that you have a two-tuple going in - is there a way to do it for any n-tuple going in (outputting a (n+1)-tuple)?

Comment: @halloleo: you can make a typeclass, and implement these for all reasonable sized tuples, like for example the `lens` package does for tuples up to 19 https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html There is however an upper limit in the number of elements of a tuple, so these are not *arbitrary* sized collections.

Comment: In fact there have been some people arguing that it might have been better to see `(a, b, c)` as a short way of `(a, (b, c))`, that would make defining instances more simpler, and the tuple type more reusable, so then only 2-tuples fundamentally exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That has rather different performance characteristics though. e.g. you have to dereference n pointers to get to the end of an n-tuple, and you have to remember it's left-biased. Getting the structure (but not the items) evaluated is now O(n) instead of O(1), etc. Current tuples are a dense chunk of memory with the right number of fields; more like an anonymous record with anonymous fields than a "container". Both have good reasons to exist (`HList`s are basically nested tuples), so I'd argue against n-tuple **syntax** being used to represent nested 2-tuples.

Comment: @halloleo The basic "problem" is that `(x, y)` and `(x, y, z)` are totally unrelated types. You can't write a function that is ambivalent to the number of items in a tuple, because all tuple sizes have different types. Typeclass heroics get you some of the way there, but it's not a lot of fun, nor a common thing to do.

Comment: I started working on a small library to append two tuples and prepend/append an element to a tuple: https://github.com/hapytex/tuple-append

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for this detailed answer. Very impressive! For me personally I think the unpacking solution (or even a solution like `info2 = ((i1,i2), 3.17)`) is more practical I think, but good to know that there *is* a more general way.

Comment: @amalloy Very good point! I still have to become a real Haskeller and "think" in types...

Comment: You can also add the fundeps `c -> a` and `c -> b` to the `TupleAdd` classes, which would make them far more usable in practice. IMO type inference usually works best if the type information flows in the opposite direction to the value information. With `TupleAppend` this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pattern to deconstruct the tuple, and then construct the new tuple.

In `ghci` you must use `let` in front of the pattern:

```
Prelude> let (nr, str) = (13, "Arrabella")
Prelude> (nr, str, 13.7)
(13,"Arrabella",13.7)
```

In a source file you type it in directly, without `let`:

```
(a, b) = (13, "Arrabella")
```

Load your source file in the interpreter with `:l sourceName.hs`, and:

```
*Main> (a, b, 13.7)
(13,"Arrabella",13.7)
```